# Make multiple Lua scripts use the same variable table?

Tags: lua

So I am writing a bunch of Lua scripts that are all running along side each other and work together. I have coded a bunch of them in such a way that they can edit files without interfering with any of the other scripts that are also editing files. Each script is running as its own Lua instance, and all of the scripts are running simultaneously.

However, I have a bunch of them which need to share the same variable table. So if the table entry of `c[1]` is changed, then every other program will have it changed at the same time.

Now I know that I could have a file or table that the files check before they do anything that involves the variables, and I know how to do that, but I want to know if I can force several programs to share the table without having to trigger an update for each one.

Also, I need to mention that I cannot simply use additional libraries. Unless you know of a way to use additional libraries with a pre-compiled binary, I can only use the normal Lua library and the socket library. For my purposes, the code needs to be fully portable and able to be executed on any Windows computer that I plug my flash drive into.

Comment: Are those scripts running within same Lua VM, or in separate instances?

Comment: I figured that it was implied that they were separate instances since they were running along side each other. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 0):

Well because they are different instances you cannot interact like that. However there is a solution. lua lanes: https://github.com/LuaLanes/lanes can be used to have multiple lua threads that can run independently and it offers linda objects that allow the sharing of data.

Comment: Edited question.

Comment: @The Elemental of Creation Well if you are using the socket library it's a bit messy but, you can have each instance use a server socket and a client socket. This way you can send data to and from each instance. To make this work you would have to sterilize your table and send the string data. But If your OS is windows you can have a precompiled binary with additional libraries. Let me know your setup and I'll help you out with that

Comment: Perhaps you could be a bit more specific when you ask about my setup. I'm going to answer you with the information I think you are asking for, but if you need more your going to need to be more specific. My guess is that you are asking what my operating system is (Windows 7) and what version of Lua I am using? I am using 5.1.(2?). I'm not sure about the last digit but I know the first two are correct. I got a pre-compiled Lua socket binary from their site.

Comment: @The Elemental of Creation  https://github.com/rjpcomputing/luaforwindows/releases
When you want to add the pre-compiled binaries to your portable app copy the binaries found in: C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\clibs and C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\lua

You only need to copy what you need the lanes module is clibs\lua51-lanes.dll and lua\lanes.lua

The files can either be in the root of your project or in their respective lua/clibs directory. Hope this helps. This is also assuming you are using lua 5.1.x 32 bit.

Comment: I don't have any binary in program files or program files (x86) also, k figured out a work around using a server that is managing all of the data, one which denies any connections that do not come from the same computer by checking the IP address of the computer it is on and comparing it to the IP address on the incoming connection.